# Uploade file/image from android to remote server

Tags: php, android, file-upload, bitmap

I am trying to upload a captured image from android device to remote server via PHP - `ftp_put()` function. The Android code is working, I just do not get it work from php side.

Explanation: On Android/Java side I encode bitmap to string and decode it in PHP ($binary). I want to upload this bitmap to remote server. Please see my PHP code:

```
<?php

if ($tag == 'upload') {

        //Get data from client
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $base = $_POST["image"];
        $date = date('Y-m-d-H-m-s');

        if (isset($base)) {
            //function creates random numbers and stores in $suffix
            $suffix = $db->createRandomID(); 

            //Prepare image name
            $image_name_ = "img_".$suffix."".$uid."_".date("Y-m-d-H-m-s").".jpg";

            // base64 encoded utf-8 string
            $binary = base64_decode($base);

            // binary, utf-8 bytes
            header("Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8");

            //Basic ftp information
            $ftp_server = "xxx.xxx.com";
            $ftp_user_name = "xxxxx";
            $ftp_user_pass = "xxxxx";
            $file = $binary;
            $remote_file = "/public_html/uploads/".$image_name_;

            // set up basic connection
            $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

            // login with username and password
            $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

            // upload a file
            if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
            $response["success"] = "Upload";
            echo json_encode($response);

            } else {
            $response["error"] = "failed";
            }

            // close the connection
            ftp_close($conn_id);
        }
?>
```

LogCat says: No such file or directory ... Line `if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII))`

Comment: Why are you using `ftp` as opposed to any normal file uploading method?

Comment: No. He (the android client) uses http/php to upload a file to a php server. But the php server tries to send it further with ftp to an ftp server. The OP could have said that.

Comment: so you encode on device -> post to server -> decode -> ftp upload to another host?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: I am trying to upload an image from android using php as webservice to ftp server, as greenapps already mentioned.

Comment: @sini Based on the error, are you sure that you have permission to put files in the `uploads` directory? Also, take note that you have a "/" at the beginning of your upload path - typically public_html is kept in your users folder or is kept in /www/var/. so in my servers case, my upload path would be: `/var/www/public_html/uploads`. 1 more note - you have `$login_result` but you don't use it. Set a breakpoint there and make sure you are successfully logging into your server. Once there, just follow your home directory up to uploads and watch your "/"s carefully

Comment: @burmat: Correct, I am using JSON to transfer from android client to php and catch with `POST['']`. I already got this work on localhost with `fwrite()` function. But currently I want my app "online".

Comment: Don't use FTP_ASCII for an image.

Comment: `LogCat says: No such file or directory`. How is that possible? You are only returning "Upload" or "failed".

Comment: `header("Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8");`.???

Comment: `/public_html/uploads/`. /public_ftp/uploads/ ? Better try without specifying a directory.

Comment: @greenapps I already changed `FTP_ASCII` to `FTP_BINARY`. And I see following error message in LogCat: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/userid/public.html/index.php

Comment: `No such file or directory`. It will print the name also. What is the name? This is a php error. So if you see it in the logcat it is not because there is an error in your app but while you logged the response of the php server. Find out if the file you want to send by ftp exists before you try to send. And just check the ftp connection by sending a file that is on the php server.